# Installing vim in centos

Tags: centos, docker

Trying to install vim on Centos 6.9 32 bit image

```
yum install vim
```

Got error:

```
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  package libacl-2.2.49-7.el6_9.1.x86_64 is already installed
  package ncurses-libs-5.7-4.20090207.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.3.el6_8.x86_64 is already installed
  package libattr-2.4.44-7.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package libselinux-2.0.94-7.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package gdbm-1.8.0-39.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64 is already installed
  file /sbin/ldconfig from install of glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
  file /sbin/sln from install of glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
  file /usr/sbin/iconvconfig from install of glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
  file /sbin/matchpathcon from install of libselinux-2.0.94-7.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libselinux-2.0.94-7.el6.i686

Error Summary
-------------
```

How to fix that error?

UPD

```
/etc/yum.conf content:
```

Adding `multilib_policy=all` in `[main]` not solves the problem

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=19&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
override_install_langs=en_US.UTF-8
tsflags=nodocs


#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
~
```

Comment: For some reason yum thinks you should be/are running a 64-bit image.

Comment: I assume this is because image runs on 64 bit OS. But how to solve this problem?

Comment: In `/etc/yum.conf` there should be a line `multilib_policy=best` change it to `multilib_policy=all`. The `multilib_policy=best` chooses the packages that are "best" for your architecture not all available architectures of packages.

Comment: my `/etc/yum.conf` not contains line `multilib_policy=all`. Adding it not solves the problem. Still have the same error. More details in UPD in question body